# NodeJS and Express interceptors

Tags: node.js, express, interceptor

I'm trying to code an interceptor for metrologie purpose. My interceptor must be called before any http query (and before Express does its job) to put some time information and after Express' job to get the duration of the call.

I'm trying with middleware and it's working fine for the "before" call but not for the "after" call, because when a route is found propagation through other middleware is stopped.

Please provide some clues to get some interceptors working in all cases.

### Edit :

What I'm trying to have is a sort of AOP for Javascript in fact...

The 'before' interceptor middleware is :

```
// JMC Add metrologie informations for all route called
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        var name = req.originalMethod + req.originalUrl;
        log.trace('Start MetroInfo for route : %s', name);
        metro.startMetrologie(name);
        return next();
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an answer with the meld npm module here : https://www.npmjs.org/package/meld

It was exactly what I needed.
Middleware is not usefull for having interceptors functionnalities.

JM.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to intercept a response consider the middleware [express-interceptor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-interceptor) it's quite easy to use and enable you to respond to requests as usual.